# How do I know if this variable is a file handle?

Tags: coldfusion

Say I have this code:

```
function doFileStuff(){
    var file = "";
    try {
        file = fileOpen(filePath);
        // do stuff with file
    }
    finally {
        fileClose(file);
    }
}
```

If the `fileOpen()` process fails, the `fileClose()` call will error.  What I need to do is this sort of thing (pseudocode):

```
if (isFile(file)){
    fileClose(file);
}
```

I know I can test if file is an empty string still, and this works for me here, but it's not testing what I should be testing: whether `file` is a file handle.  I can check the object's Java class, but this again sounds a bit hacky to me, and there should be a CFML way of doing it.

There should be something like just `isFile()`, shouldn't there?  I can't find anything like this in the docs.

Any thoughts / tips?  I have gone into more depth in my investigations on my [blog](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/how-do-i-know-if-this-variable-is-file.html).  it's too wordy for here.

Comment: Adam, could you use one of the returned keys for the file handler to test whether or not it's "real". Maybe something like if(file.size > 0){ // do your thing }? My sense is that if file.size returns a positive value, it's probably a real file. Perhaps that's too basic for your needs? Just a thought!

Comment: And I would LOVE to see an isFile() method appear in CF going forward. If they have isImageFile and isPDFFile certainly we can have isFile :)!

Comment: I do not think the option you are looking for exists. Though I agree there should be *something*.  You run into similar issues in java with how to close a file stream in a `finally` clause without adding an ugly try/catch. Apache's approach to it was to create a [closeQuietly](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly%28java.io.InputStream%29) method. I kind of like that idea better than an `IsFile` method. At least in this *specific* scenario ..

Comment: ie For example if the FileClose method accepted a second parameter  `FileClose( object, throwOnError )`

Comment: @Leigh Good point. For now you can write a wrapper like `FileCloseSilent(object)` and perform `FileClose` inside try/catch in it, whatever the result would be.

Comment: @Sergii - Yeah, it is obviously not exactly the same situation, since CF has the whole typeless issue on top of any errors that might occur when calling `FileClose()/close()`. But given that there is no built in method of handling either issue, that approach may be as clean as it gets.

Comment: I agree with Craig on this because it meshes with other functionality (like isImage, isNull, isQuery, isObject etc).

Comment: An `IsFile` function might be useful, but it still does not fully address the *entire* issue with file i/o. Namely errors that might still occur in a `finally` clause. So I still think you need something more than just `IsFile`.

Comment: @Leigh, sure.  I didn't say it was a panacea ;-)  One can put another try/catch in the finally and take "emergency" remedial action if the file close operation fails too.  In my case "letting it error" is the most appropriate thing to have happen in this situation, hence no attempts to deal with it further.

Comment: @Adam - Haha, true. I am just throwing out other considerations for those who come across this thread later, since the desired i/o handling often "depends" on the app. Personally I would like to see both functions: `FileClose(obj, throwOnError)` and `IsFile(obj)`. (But the bug db is a better place for suggestions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm marking this as answered: basically there is no native way of doing it.  I've [raised a ticket with Adobe](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3299625) to get it sorted.

Thanks for all the feedback.

UPDATE: According to that ticket I raised, this has been implemented as `isFileObject()` in ColdFusion 11.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. I'd use the `java.io.File` class. It's what CF uses internally for its file operations, with the exception of the new vfs feature.

Leveraging java shouldn't be considered hacky. It's a down right necessity sometimes ;-)

Comment: Actually I believe it uses `RandomAccessFile`. Agreed there is nothing wrong with using java, when needed.  I suspect the "hacky" comment was about the gap in the native functions, rather than eschewing java in general ;) The scenario above is a pretty typical as far as basic file handling goes. So while one could use java, if CF is going to provide native file handling functions, it really should provide a way to handle the *complete* cycle - natively. Just my $0.02..

Comment: One of the downsides to not using cf's built in methods is that it costs a little bit extra to call the java methods from cf as it uses reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I expanded the functionality of an existing TypeOf() UDF to add support to return any variable type. You can use it to determine whether the variable is type "FileHandler" (or "FileHandlerJava") and then close it accordingly. It works with ColdFusion 9+.  I post this solution because we aren't upgrading to CF11.

**TypeOf() UDF (and sample usage)**

https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/1ed396431dfb8e0e9f58

```
 /* Detect CF's fileOpen() */
if (typeOf(theFile) is "fileHandler"){
    fileClose(file);

/* Detect createobject("java","java.io.FileReader") */
else if (typeOf(theFile) is "fileHandlerJava"){
    variables['file'].close();
}
```

Comment: Full disclosure: Your github acct